# Expression Tree search using contains

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, expression-trees, contains

EDITED:

I'm trying to create a query using Expression Trees so that I can obtain a simple result, but I haven't been able of figuring it out.

I've got some entities from EF.
Entity PointOfSale , that has some attributes like:
Location (that is a child of Region)
TypeOfClient
ImportanceOfPOS
QuantityOfSales.

Then I have a class Filter, that has a list of Regions, a list of TypesOfClients, a Dist of ImportanceOfPOS, and a minimum and maximum value for the quantity of sales.

The classes are defined below:

Entities context = new Entities();

```
class PointOfSale 
{
    int p_id;
    Location l;
    QuantityOfSales q;
    TypeOfCliente t;
    ImportanceOfClient i;
    int l_id_fk;
    int t_id_fk;
    int i_id_fk;
}

class Location
{
    int id;
    int region_id_fk;
}

class Region
{
     int id;
     string value;
}

class ValuesForQuantity
{
    int p_id; // ---> Equal to the POS_id
    int? min_value;
    int? max_value;
}

class QuantityOfSales
{
     int id;
     int value;
}

class TypeOfCliente
{
    int id;
    string value;
}

class ImportanceOfClient;
{
    int id;
    string value;
}


class Filter
{
     List<Region> rs;
     ValuesForQuantity v;
     List<ImportanceOfClient> is;
     List<TypeOfClient> ts;
}
```

Keep in mind that all the fields are optional:
I may or may not have regions, I may or may not have TypeOfClient. Also, in ValueForQuantities, I may have just one of the fields chosen (just maximum or minimum).

I'm trying to build a dynamic version of this:

```
var query = 
    from p in context.PointsOfSale
    where p.i exists in filter.is  &&
          p.t exists in filter.ts  &&
          p.l in (from l1 in context.Locations where l1 in filter.rs select r) &&
          p.t in (from q in context.Quantities where q.value < filter.v.max_value && q.value > filter.v.max_value)
    select p;
```

Which will generate a code like this:

```
(p.i.id == filter.i[0] OR p.i.id == filter.i[1] OR p.i.id == filter.i[2])
AND
(p.t.id == filter.t[0] OR p.t.id == filter.t[1])
AND
p.l in (select id from Region r where (r.id == filter.r[0] OR r.id == filter.r[1])
AND
p.q.value < filter.v.max
AND
p.q.value > filter.v.min
```

My expression tree so far is this:

```
IQueryable<Points_of_sale> queryableDataPOS = context.Points_of_sale.AsQueryable<Points_of_sale>();
ParameterExpression pePOS = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Points_of_sale), "point_of_sale");
ParameterExpression peLocation = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Location), "location");
        List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();

if (showRegion)
        {
            List<Location> ls = getAllLocations(regionList);
            List<Expression> choiceExpressions = new List<Expression>();
            foreach (Location l in ls)
            {
                Expression left = Expression.Property(pePOS, typeof(Points_of_sale).GetProperty("location_id_fk"));
                left = Expression.Convert(left, t.location_id.GetType());
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(t.territory_id);

                Expression expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                choiceExpressions.Add(expression);
            }
            if (choiceExpressions.Count > 0)
            {
                Expression totalChoiceExpression = choiceExpressions[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < choiceExpressions.Count; i++)
                {
                    totalChoiceExpression = Expression.Or(totalChoiceExpression, choiceExpressions[i]);
                }
                expressions.Add(totalChoiceExpression);
            }
        }

if (showTypeOfClient)
        {
            List<Expression> choiceExpressions = new List<Expression>();
            foreach (TypeOfClient choice in clients)
            {
                Expression left = Expression.Property(pePOS, typeof(Points_of_sale).GetProperty("type_of_client_id_fk"));
                left = Expression.Convert(left, choice.type_of_client.GetType());
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(choice.type_of_client_id);
                Expression expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                choiceExpressions.Add(expression);
            }
            if (choiceExpressions.Count > 0)
            {
                Expression totalChoiceExpression = choiceExpressions[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < choiceExpressions.Count; i++)
                {
                    totalChoiceExpression = Expression.Or(totalChoiceExpression, choiceExpressions[i]);
                }
                expressions.Add(totalChoiceExpression);
            }
        }

if (showImportanceOfClient)
        {
            List<Expression> choiceExpressions = new List<Expression>();
            foreach (ImportanceOfClient choice in importanceOfClients)
            {
                Expression left = Expression.Property(pePOS, typeof(Points_of_sale).GetProperty("importance_of_client_id_fk"));
                left = Expression.Convert(left, choice.importance_of_client_id.GetType());
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(choice.importance_of_client_id);
                Expression expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                choiceExpressions.Add(expression);
            }
            if (choiceExpressions.Count > 0)
            {
                Expression totalChoiceExpression = choiceExpressions[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < choiceExpressions.Count; i++)
                {
                    totalChoiceExpression = Expression.Or(totalChoiceExpression, choiceExpressions[i]);
                }
                expressions.Add(totalChoiceExpression);
            }
        }

if (showQuantityOfSales)
{
    // I have no idea how to build this one
}

Expression totalQuery = expressions[0];

// Make the && between all expressions
for (int i = 1; i < expressions.Count; i++)
{
    totalQuery = Expression.And(totalQuery, expressions[i]);
}

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { queryableDataPOS.ElementType },
            queryableDataPOS.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Points_of_sale, bool>>(totalQuery, new ParameterExpression[] { pePOS }));

IQueryable<Points_of_sale> results = queryableDataPOS.Provider.CreateQuery<Points_of_sale>(whereCallExpression);
```

So, 2 questions:

1 - How can I build the region part without the method that returns all the locations.
2 - How can I create the expression tree branch for the Quantity part?

Tnks a lot and I hope it's now clear :)

Answer (score 1):

First, build a LambdaExpression from your expression "sub". Then build the "Contains" call (actually it is a call to Queryable.Any):

```
var anyExpression = Expression.Call("Queryable.Any", sequence, lambda);
```

You are building this expression:

```
Queryable.Any(sequence, x => x > 5);
```

Edit: It looks like you don't need to build an expression tree at all. What about this:

```
var query = context.P_List;

if(filter.zs != null && filter.zs.Count != 0)
 query = query.Where(p => filter.zs.Contains<int>(p.z));

if(filter.ys != null && filter.ys.Count != 0)
 query = query.Where(p => filter.ys.Contains<int>(p.y));

if(filter.as != null && filter.as.Count != 0)
 query = query.Where(p => (from ac in context.a_child where filter.as.Contains(ac) select a).Contains(p.a_child));

//and the same for v2...

var list = query.ToList(); //execute the SQL
```

I hope that works.

Comment: I am a little lost on what exactly you want. Can you write the query you want to build as a complete linq query? I can then add some code to show how such a query can be built using expressions.

Comment: I provided an alternative. Please tell me if this fits your need. I think it does. L2S will convert the "Contains" call into an "IN" SQL clause which is equivalent to your ORs.

Comment: usr, tnks a lot. I'll try it as soon as I'm finished with other obligations and I'll let you know :)

Comment: That are two problems with this solution:
First:
 You can't use Contains<int>, cause p.z is not an int. And I'm not sure if it will allow me to use the expression Contains with entities (cause EF has a know issue with that).
Second:
 "query = query.Where" has a cast problem. The first one is a DbSet<P> and the second an IQueryable<P>. If I make the cast explicit, I get a runtime cast exception error.

Comment: Ok, so I've changed "query = context.P_List.AsQueryable()". So the second error is no more. Now the first problem I said arises, as I get an exception saying "Unable to create a constant value of type Z. Only primitives are supported in this context".

Comment: Does not sound like this was a general problem with this approach. You can probably make it work. If you still want some help to build this query post your current code.

Comment: I do :)
I'm now going to post my code here. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Done. I'd really appreciate some help :)

Comment: The best advice I can give is to construct a fully wrking LINQ query manually with hardcoded values and lists. Then look at the expression tree the compiler generates (you can find on the internet how to do that). Once you know how a working tree looks like you can construct it yourself.

Comment: The problem is quite hard to understand for an outsider so I am not going to come up with working code for you. I think there are no major hurdles left for you though.

Comment: I'm not even sure on how to build the linq query, since I can't use "contains" with EF. My biggest question now is how to build the part that says "I have no idea how to build this one". Thanks for the help, though :)

Comment: Do it like this: Instead of "Contains" you use "or": where obj.someProperty == 1 || obj.someProperty == 2 || ...; just like you try to do with expressions. You don't have to use Contains.